# Setting Page.Title from the codebehind of a Sitecore sublayout (user control) doesn't work

Tags: user-controls, sitecore, title, code-behind, page-title

I'm having an issue setting Page.Title for a page from the codebehind of a usercontrol (sublayout).

We have a layout, MainLayout.aspx. I can set the page title from the codebehind of this page, and it works fine. However, if, after this, I try to set the page title in the codebehind of MySublayout1, the new value is set for the Page.Title property, but the change is not reflected on the page.

I've tried moving the code from the  Page_Load to the OnInit events for both the page and the control, but nothing seems to work. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for this is creating an new rendering or sublayout that renders the -section of your page. So you can set the values in literals or sc:text controls in the sublayout instead of setting only the Page.Title from codebehind. 
This way you can set more properties all at once like the meta-keywords and meta-description, based on the current Sitecore Item.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add the following to the layout or sublayout that is in it:

```
<head runat="server" id="_Head">
    <title><sc:FieldRenderer ID="frTitle" runat="server" FieldName="title" /></title>
</head>
```

Also make sure that you call `DataBind();` or set `Sitecore.Context.State.DataBind` to true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Sublayout to override the title set in the Layout, you can move the code in the Layout to `Page_Init` and use `Page_Load` in your Sublayout.

If that doesn't work, then your Sublayout may have trouble accessing the Page. You can try using `WebUtil.CurrentPage.Title` to access the current page title. It might also require that you set runat="server" on the head and title elements as follows:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title runat="server"></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this:

< title> <%=Sitecore.Context.Item["PageTitleFieldName"] %> < /title>

It works fine to render page title from given field.